# How can I trigger a script in my host machine from a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localhost

I have a script in my host machine that needs to run everytime an action occurs within a docker container (running a Django Rest API). This script depends on many local files and environment variables, so it is not possible for me to just map everything (volumes and env vars) from the host to the container in order for it to be called inside it. It must be called from the host machine. After it is executed, then it will generate some output files that will be read and used from the container (through a mounted volume).

Is there any way I can achieve this? I've seen lots of comments about using docker socket and mapping volumes, but it never seems to be suitable to this case.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by *everytime an action occurs*?

Comment: It may be excessive but could you ssh from the container to the host? ssh is general-purpose (well-tried|test). This would give you a shell (and an environment) in which you could run the script. You should consider creating a specific user for for this task and limit its access to only what's needed.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, everytime a request is sent to a particular endpoint.